# Taking user input using an employee class, storing it into an array and displaying in main method- Java

Tags: java, class, arraylist, input

I am new to programming and have spent last number of days trying to take user input, store it in an arraylist and then output the specific details. I would really appreciate someone shining some light on where I'm going wrong. I cant seem to be able to access the input from the employee class and store it in the arraylist in the main Method.

Thanks.

```
public class OctEmployeeArray{

public void menu(){

    boolean breakOut= false;
    while(breakOut == false){
        System.out.println("=====================================");            
        System.out.println("=====================================");        
        System.out.println("EMPLOYEE HOLIDAY ENTITLEMENT PROGRAM");
        System.out.println("Please chose the appropriate option: ");

        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println("1) Enter new employee details:");
        System.out.println("2) Display the employee average age:");
        System.out.println("3) Display information on specific employee:");
        System.out.println("4) Display all database accounts:");
        System.out.println("5) Exit the program:");
        System.out.println("=====================================");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    //scanner assigned to 'in'
        String choice = in.nextLine();  //user input stored in choice

        switch (choice){
            case "1": System.out.println("You chose the 'add employee' input");
                Employee e1= new Employee();
                e1.addEmployee();
                break;

            case "2": 
                System.out.println("You chose the b input");
                break;

            case "3":   
                System.out.println("You chose the c input");
               //searchspecficEmployee();   
               break;

            case "4":
                System.out.println("You chose the 'display all' input");
                //displayAll();
                break;

            case "5":
                System.out.println("You chose to Exit.");
                breakOut= true;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("The input is not accurate");
                break;
        }
    }   
}

public class Employee {
    private String staffName;
    private int staffNumber;
    private int staffAge;
    private int yearStarted;
    private String role;


    public Employee(String staffName, int staffAge, int yearStarted, int staffNumber, String role){
        this.staffName= staffName;
        this.staffNumber= staffNumber;
        this.staffAge= staffAge;
        this.yearStarted= yearStarted;
        this.role= role;            
    }

    public Employee(){

    }

    public int getAge(){
        return staffAge;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return staffName;
    }

    public int getStaffNum(){
        return staffNumber;
    }

    public int getStartYear(){
        return yearStarted;
    }

    public Employee addEmployee(){//this asks the new employee questions, saves them in a employee object called e

        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        //Employee d= new Employee();
        System.out.println("Please enter your Full name:");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your age:");
        int age= Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter your staff number:");
        int staffNum= Integer.parseInt (in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter year of current employment:");
        int startYear=Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter role employment:");
        String role=in.nextLine();

        Employee e= new Employee(name, age, startYear, staffNum, role);// puts all the varibles and puts them inside e and returns it
        return e;
    }

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employee> alist= new ArrayList();// arraylist created to save employee objects
        OctEmployeeArray o= new OctEmployeeArray();// object created for access to main menu    
        o.menu();//display main menu

        Employee em= new Employee();// create employee object to access add employee method
        alist.add(em.addEmployee);

        for(Employee count : alist){
            System.out.println(count.getName());
            System.out.println(count.getStaffNum());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the code to the specific areas of the problem and elaborate on what is not working? http://idownvotedbecau.se/

Comment: "alist.add(em.addEmployee);" change it to "  alist.add(em.addEmployee());" wrong method call

Comment: It will be better if you ask what error you are getting or where did it stuck to give the output instead putting all the code to be checked by techies. By seeing your code I feel it will be a good If you will segregate your code. Let's take an example ,You created `Employee` as a class to have data and you added method `addEmployee` into that same class, what I feel you can take Employee as a model  only and have different class to hold you business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `Employee` instance inside the `addEmployee()` method. That's not wrong. But the fact this method is inside the `Employee` class is semantically nonsense (sorry) - and i think it's also why it doesn't work (It's a coincidence. Unfortunately a lot of semantic nonsense does work.).

What you should do is to remove the `addEmployee()` method from the `Employee` class and move it to the class holding your Employee array. Don't create new `Employee` instances inside the `Employee` class.